# How can I explain this integer partitions function recursion?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, recursion

How to explain how this algorithm works? I need to write an article about this but I can't explain why this recursion works fine.

It defines the number of partitions of a given integer

```
function p(sum,largest):
    if largest==0: return 0
    if sum==0: return 1
    if sum<0: return 0
    return p(sum, largest-1) + p(sum-largest, largest)
```

(call: p(n,n))

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This function is the same as $F(n, k)$ which is the number of partitions of $n$ such that no element in the partition is greater than $k$ (assuming $k <= n$).

Using this function $F(n, n)$ denotes the number of partitions of $n$ as no element in the partition of $n$ can be greater than $n$.

The base conditions $F(0, k) = 1$ and $F(-m, k) = 0$ are by the definition of the partition function $P(n)$ which represents the total number of partitions of $n$ ($m > 0$). $F(n, 0) = 0$ as $n$ cannot be partitioned such that no element in the partition is greater than $0$.

Now as for the last statement in the function, think of $F(n, k)$ - the number of partitions of $n$ such that no element in a partition is greater than $k$ - as the union of two mutually exclusive sets, first set containing all the partitions such that all elements in a partition are less than $k$ and the second set containing all the partitions such that at least one element in each partition is equal to $k$.

Clearly the cardinality of first set is $F(n, k-1)$ and the cardinality of the second set is 
$F(n-k, k)$ because we have already chosen $k$ as an element in a partition so now we have to partition $n-k$.

Clearly the the above two sets are mutually exclusive therefore,

$F(n, k) = F(n, k-1) + F(n-k, k)  $

Comment: Your text is beautiful.

Comment: Thank you. Glad that it helped you.

Answer (score 5):

The terminology *largest* is misleading: the idea is actually that $p(n,m)$ is the number of partitions of $n$ whose largest part is **at most** $m$, not the number whose largest part **is** $m$. This function is usually denoted by $q$, as in [this reference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionq.html).

Now look at the stopping conditions of the algorithm. The first one is that $p(n,0)$ is always $0$; that makes sense, since a partition has to have a positive part. Skip the next line for a moment; if $n<0\ne m$, $p(n,m)=0$; that also makes sense, since partitions of negative integers aren’t defined. The middle stopping condition says that if $m\ne 0$, then $p(0,m)=1$, which probably looks a bit odd. It turns out, however, to make life simpler if we say by convention that the integer $0$ has $1$ partition.

What’s left to explain is the actual recurrence:

$$p(n,m)=p(n,m-1)+p(n-m,m)\text{ if }m,n\ne 0\;.$$

Consider the partitions of $n$ with no part bigger than $m$.

1. Some of them actual have no part equal to $m$, either; how many of those are there?
2. The rest all have at least one part equal to $m$. Take away that part, and what’s left is a partition of what integer? And what’s the largest possible size of the remaining parts?

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

Can you actually use relatively small numbers and work through the algorithm to allow you to see what is happening?

Then, look at the area labeled 'Intermediate Function' on [this web site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) and see if you can work through this.

You can also look at the recurrence relation [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html).

HTH ~A